# How to avoid loading Expo notifications bundle for web build?

Tags: node.js, react-native, expo, react-native-web

I am using expo and react native web. I have integrated FCM for notifications for web but expo also loads a notifications bundle which I do not want.

The issue is when the notification is received in the browser and message is clicked, the app gets the focus but crashes saying “TypeError: _emitter is undefined”. This is on this line in src/Notifications/Notifications.ts:40

```
_emitter.emit('notification', notification);
```

So, it seems expo tries to use its Notifications module. Can I remove that for web build?

Answer (score 0):

**Solution 1 - Upgrade to expo@39.0.4:**

```
npm install expo@39.0.4
```

**Solution 2 - Initialize _emitter property**

1. Install the following package:

```
npm install --save fbemitter
```

2. Add a listener in your App.js/tsx file

```
    import * as Notifications from 'expo/build/Notifications/Notifications'
    
    // By calling "Notifications.default.addListener()" function,
    // the _emitter variable will be initialized correctly
    Notifications.default.addListener(event => {
      console.log('message data', event.data)
    })
```