# How do I use Firebase with Expo

Tags: node.js, react-native, expo, react-native-web

Currently Expo only supports push notifications for Android and iOS. How do I implement push notifications with Firebase?

Answer (score 0):

To implement Firebase for Expo web you need to do the following:

1. Ensure you are using *at least* Expo 39.0.4. See [How to avoid loading Expo notifications bundle for web build?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65368235/how-to-avoid-loading-expo-notifications-bundle-for-web-build/65368236)
2. Ensure you're using the latest version of Firebase `npm install firebase@latest`
3. Create your `register-service-worker.js` file using `expo customize:web`
4. Update your code using the following Github repo as a reference: [expo-fcm-pwa](https://github.com/JeSuisAlrick/expo-fcm-pwa)